# Using FlexBox to constrain half of page content

Tags: html, css

I'm building a simple UI using React (shouldn't matter though) to configure some IoT sensors that I have. This page will have a header, a footer, and the main page content. The main page content will be (more or less) split in two, with a list of sensors on the left, that scrolls to accommodate, and a way to configure the sensors on the right. This won't need to scroll, as there will only be 4-5 options, which easily fits on a page. While I mostly have this working, my solution feels incredibly hacky, and I'm almost certain it will break given the slightest push, but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

My HTML/JSX looks like this:

```
<section class="home-page hero is-fullheight is-default is-bold">
    <div class="hero-head" ...>
    <div class="hero-body columns">
        <div class="column is-5 sensors">{sensors}</div>
        <div class="column is-7 sensor-config">Config Goes Here</div>
    </div>
    <Footer />
</section>
```

SCSS:

```
.home-page {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .hero-body {
    flex-shrink: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92%;

    .sensors {
      display: block;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-right: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
      padding: 40px 20px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .sensor-config {
      display:block;
      background-color: #fff;
      padding: 40px 20px;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces the following: [image: View of the site using the code above] The left panel is scrolled all the way down, and I apologize for all the white-on-white, trying to get the structure correct first.

The very specific height percentages is what looks hacky to me, though perhaps I'm wrong? I can't figure out anyway to not use them, without breaking the look completely. If I remove the 92%, the sensor list pushes the footer right out the bottom of the screen, and if I remove the 100% from the sensor list, it goes off both vertical ends of the page, with the footer and header just on top of it, z-index wise.

Comment: you could always change the hero direction to column, and then add in another flex container that is row-based. What's bad about not seeing the footer exactly?

Comment: It's difficult to say why you would need `92%` `height` from your code and a full MVCE may help in this regard. However, it's likely to be a problem arising from `position`. Try adding `position: relative` to the element, and check that it's not overlapping anything in the F12 Debugger. Other than that, you can always do something like `calc(100% - footer_height)`

Comment: have you thought about displaying the page out using grid?

Comment: @Jhect I didn't even think about that. What's bad about not seeing the footer is that I simply don't like the look. Because the right pane is static, if you want to select the lowest sensor element, you'll need to scroll down, click on the left, and scroll back up to edit on the top right. It would be very poor. I haven't thought about using grid, as I don't have much experience with it, but will look into that.

Comment: example grid layout https://jsfiddle.net/qb9wodrv/1/

Comment: @ObsidianAge Add `position: relative` to what, exactly? As for doing the height with a calc, I can't, as far as I know, as the height isn't static. There is no set value there. It also grows as need be.

Comment: @Jhect That grid looks freaking awesome. I didn't know it had that power. I can only respond now, so I'll try to implement later, but that certainly looks like it does what I want, so long as I can make it work with mobile too. Thanks